# Conflict in Imaginary parts after IFFT

Tags: c, matlab, signal-processing, fft, ifft

I wanted to know the reasoning behind a conflict ONLY in imaginary parts after IFFT.

For both my C/C++ implementation and Matlab implemenation I am doing the same following steps.

1. My signal *x* is of dimension *Mx1* and I perform an *N*-point FFT (where *N* = 2**M*) on that signal to get *N*-point signal in frequency domain.
2. Apply a customized filter on this frequency domain signal (both real and imaginary parts are changed in step).
3. Perform in *N*-point inverse FFT.

Both C/C++ and Matlab implementations generate exactly the same result except the after the inverse IFFT step, **imaginary parts do not match but real parts do match**.

If I skip step 2 above, IFFT output of both implementation match without any problem.
It is intended that my input signal to IFFT (i.e., after step2 filter) is not required to be conjugate symmetric. Infact this signal may even not be a Hermitian/symmetric.

Currently, I am using C-implementation of FFT/IFFT defined as a function `smbFft` available in this [CPP-FILE](http://downloads.dspdimension.com/smbPitchShift.cpp).

Any clues, why this could be happening?

PS: It would be great, if someone can point me to an FFT implementation in C/C++, which is exactly aligned with corresponding Matlab implementation.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I just tested FFTW implementation instead of `smbFfT` (I mentioned above). FFTW implementation also has the same problem, which suggest that both of these tested C-implementations perform IFFT with hermitian symmetry setting. I need to perform the same IFFT in C as Matlab does with `IFFT(..., 'nonsymmetric')`.

Comment: Post your code. Specially, beware of Matlab `'` operator, which applies a complex conjugation

Comment: try FFT -> IFFT *without* other changes with both codes too confirm the inverse operation in your C code is correct. The results should be equal to the input (taking into account numerical precison)

Comment: @Sebastien I just edited above, I skip step 2 above, the output of IFFT matches with Matlab's IFFT.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for your pointer. I am aware of this operation.

Comment: Do you use the exact same filter in both cases? I used to use fftw for C code. very efficient and robust.

Comment: @LuisMendo Currently, I am using the FFT/IFFT implemenation from DSP-dimension, available as `smbFft(...)` in this file [link](http://downloads.dspdimension.com/smbPitchShift.cpp)

Comment: @Sebastien Yes, I used the same exact filter in both implementations. Infact, for both implementations, I have validated the output of step 2 (i.e., the input to IFFT) and they match.

Comment: What is the relative mismatch? Does your original function has an imaginary part? If you try the whole thing with a known analytic function, does it works?

Comment: @Sebastien: Imaginary parts differs significantly in their magnitudes as well as signs. Should I provide the output of step 2?

Comment: Try with an analytic function (a lorentizian or a gaussian).

Comment: @Sebastien Yes it does work. 
Note that, because of the filter in step2, IFFT should output non-zero imaginary parts (instead of zero magnitude of imaginary part). 
My guess is it may be that smbFft FFT/IFFT does not support some special case of FFT/IFFT, which is handled well in Matlab. But still no clue why its happening.

Comment: Is your filter Hermitian? Is the FFT result hermitian too? If so, the problem is most probably related to the code that applies it. The most frequent error that shows these symptoms is a damning offset in your array values (1 to n vs 0 to n-1). Beyond that, not sure I can help

Comment: @Sebastien Thanks for your help. Indexing the array is not the issue. 
Do you know any C implementation of FFT/IFFT, which claims to match with corresponding Matlab implementation.

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is fftw.org fast, reliable, and easy to add to a project.

Comment: OK thanks for your help.
I just found out, in matlab if I run ifft(..., 'nonsymmetric') I get the same result as I was getting initially. In other words, Matlab somehow automatically selected 'nonosymmetric' when I did not give any. Running with ifft(..., 'symmetric') only output real part, no imaginary part. Have to dig a bit deeper why Matlab.ifft is working like this.

Comment: @Sebastien I tried fftw3 implementation of FFT/IFFT. The imaginary parts of fftw3.IFFT(p) also do not match to Matlab.IFFT(..., 'non-symmetric'). Since result of my filter is required not to be Hermitian. That's why I want to perform a IFFT with non-symmetry enabled. What I feel is most C-implementations perform IFFT with Hermitian/symmetric setting.

Comment: Well at that point I guess you should review matlab and fftw documentation relative to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a strictly real result (imaginary parts all equal to zero), then you need to make the vector be exactly conjugate symmetric (real parts mirrored, imaginary parts inversely mirrored) before the IFFT.

Matlab and C treat index 0 or 1 of arrays differently.  Make sure your filter takes that into account as well.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. It is intended that my input signal to IFFT (i.e., after step2 filter) is not required to be conjugate symmetric. Hence, I know the after IFFT would not yield imaginary part as zero. That's not the problem. The problem is imaginary part is still important to me after IFFT. But the C-implementation (I mentioned above) computes different values of imaginary than in comparison to Matlab.IFFT implementation. In other words, these two IFFT implementations are in conflict while dealing with same input non-symmetric signal.